# Spa can't find bundle.js

Tags: reactjs, asp.net-core

I'm trying to serve a SPA. I intend to send a single index.html and have the site be rendered in the client.

The problem is when I load the site from a path that is not the root path, It no longer finds the site.js static file anymore.

This is my Startup.cs

```
    public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
    {
        services.Configure<CookiePolicyOptions>(options =>
        {
            options.CheckConsentNeeded = context => true;
            options.MinimumSameSitePolicy = SameSiteMode.None;
        });
        services.AddSpaStaticFiles(configuration =>
        {
            configuration.RootPath = "wwwroot";
        });
    }
    public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IHostingEnvironment env)
    {
        if (env.IsDevelopment())
        {
            app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();
            app.UseDatabaseErrorPage();
        }
        else
        {
            app.UseExceptionHandler("/Home/Error");
            app.UseHsts();
        }
        app.UseHttpsRedirection();
        app.UseMvc();
        app.UseStaticFiles();
        app.UseSpaStaticFiles();

        app.UseSpa(spa=>{
            spa.Options.SourcePath = "wwwroot";
        });
     }
```

This is my index.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport"
      content="width=device-width, user-scalable=no, initial-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0, minimum-scale=1.0">
    <title>Title</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div id="root"></div>
    <script src="site.js"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

my wwwroot folder has the 2 files index.html and site.js

Whenever I load https:localhost:5001/ the site works fine, but if I add a route to the site it no longer finds site.js

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try changing your script path to:

```
<script src="/site.js"></script>
```

Comment: Oh... that was it. Thanks.